# What happened to design view in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio has the option to view html in 3 views: design, split an source. (image from VS2012)

[image]

All 3 options seem to have disappeared in Visual Studio 2013.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do this:

```
right click on file which you wish to open.
Then Open with application and choose
```

> HTML (Web Forms) Editor

Set as default (on right side) if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Go figure though. Why would they hide this feature in this way? I would never have found it there.

Comment: Just confirmed this still works in Visual Studio 2015 RTM.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason (today I encountered it) that the .html file
was added to the Solution with *Add > Existing Item... > Add As Link*.
In this case VS never offered the Design view. When I re-added the very
same file normally (not “As Link”), the Design view appeared. :(

It's a shame that you cannot ‘Design view’ external .html files that don't reside within the folder tree of your project.